# How can I manipulate the error messages that sbt outputs?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to make them more readable in the context of the common errors for our specific project - without actually recompiling sbt if that is even possible.

Comment: Hmm can you specify which error messages you wanted to manipulate? If it's the stack trace then I don't think it's possible unless you catch and throw your own exception